# Jython 2.1 __getattr__

Tags: python, jython, word-wrap, setattr, getattr

I am trying to implement a wrapper/proxy class for a java object (baseClient) in jython v2.1. Everything seems to be working ok except when the following statement is encountered:

```
if __client != None # __client is an instance of the ClientProxy class
```

`raise AttributeError(attr)` is called in `__getattr__()`, because `self.__baseClient` doesn't have `__ne__` attribute.
It's important to mention that I cannot upgrade because jython is a part of a system. Is there a way to get around this issue?

```
class ClientProxy:
    def __init__(self, baseClient):
        self.__baseClient = baseClient
        self.__initialised = 1

    def __getattr__(self, attr):
        if not self.__dict__.has_key('_ClientProxy__initialised'):
            raise AttributeError(attr)
        else:
            if hasattr(self.__baseClient, attr):
                return getattr(self.__baseClient, attr)
            else:
                raise AttributeError(attr)


    def __setattr__(self, attr, val):
        if not self.__dict__.has_key('_ClientProxy__initialised'):
            self.__dict__[attr] = val
            return

        if hasattr(self.__baseClient, attr):
            self.__baseClient.__setattr__(attr, val)
        else:
            self.__dict__[attr] = val
```

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if __client != None:
```

For testing against specific instances such as None, it's idiomatic to use the identity operator:

```
if __client is not None:
```

This will avoid the problem of calling comparators.

However, the fact that `__getattr__` raises `AttributeError` should not be a problem. The comparator should call `getattr` speculatively for `__cmp__` (`__ne__` first on newer Pythons), and if it gets an `AttributeError` it is supposed to silently swallow it and fall back to identity comparison instead. Why does the `AttributeError` cause a problem in your case?

Comment: After posting this question I noticed that AttributeError actually is raised three times - for `__ne__`, for `__coerce__` and for `__cmp__` in that order, but it's not causing any problems.
I left the question just to understand what is going on.

Thanks for the quick and informative answer!